# Regular expression - finding the numbers inside brackets AFTER a certain word

Tags: python, regex

Here I have a string in the format as follows:

```
Board: [Qd 6c Kc 8s Ad]

Player STACKS5143 does not show cards.Bets: 0.15. Collects: 0. Loses: 0.15.

Player REAGANBUSH84 does not show cards.Bets: 0.15. Collects: 0. Loses: 0.15.

Player HossaRules does not show cards.Bets: 0. Collects: 0. Wins: 0.

Player xrayoki does not show cards.Bets: 0. Collects: 0. Wins: 0.

Player sykoteekho shows: High card A [7c 9c]. Bets: 3.29. Collects: 0. Loses: 3.29.

*Player Autobot shows: One pair of Ks [Ks Jh]. Bets: 3.29. Collects: 6.54. Wins: 3.25.

Game ended at: 2018/2/19 15:59:26
```

And I want to find the numbers inside the brackets ONLY AFTER the word `show`

Is there a way to do this?

I tried this here: `(show.+ | \[.+\])`
But seems like it is picking up other brackets that I don't want.

Any ideas would be great

Thank you,

Comment: The bracketed term never appears immediately after the word `show`.  Can you clarify your problem?

Comment: Yes -- I would like to look per row and grab the brackets after it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here:

```
show.+\[([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)\]
```

will match only "7c 9c" and "Ks Jh" as group "$1".

Demo: [here](https://regex101.com/r/F43UHz/1)

As long as the players are not allowed to have brackets in their usernames, it should even work with players having "show" as substring in the name.

Answer (score 1):

1. Looks like you need *`shows`* for the keyword.
2. Line based, ie. don't span lines.
3. Single brackets.

Try `shows.*?\[([^\[\]\r\n]*)\]`

where $1 (group 1) contains the bracket contents.